# Jquery Mobile read document in dynamic list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing Phonegap App with JqueryMobile.i want to create a dynmaic list that show each element

I have 3 html files and 1 php file: index.html > list.html > details.html
JS is inside html files.

I use jquery-1.6.4.min.js & jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js

index.html:

```
 ...
    HTML
    ...
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#button").click(function(){
      $.post("myURL", {myparameters}, function(data) {
       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
         var lista = $("\
         <td style='width:100px;height:100px' >\
          <a href='details.html' id='details' class='details' value='"+obj[i]["id"]+"'>\
           <img style='width:100px;height:100px' src='"+image+"'>\
          </a>\
         </td>");

        list.appendTo("#...");
        }
       });
      });
     });
    </script
```

>

list.html:

```
...
HTML
...

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".details").click(function(){
   $.post("myURL", {myparameters}, function(data) 
   {
  *Here I load details data*
   });

 });
});
</script>
```

Problems/Questions:

- $(document).ready(function){...}; load dynamic list only once.When i go to other menu,data from list.html dissapear.
- When I click in some element from list.html,jquery code dont load data in details.html
- JQ 1.6.4 & JQM 1.4.5 are okey?

I know that i do something wrong about read the document.I read JqueryMobile documentation and I tried other methods like:

$(document).on('pagecreate',function()...

$(document).on('pagebeforecreate',function()...

$(document).on('pageinit',function()...

but didn't work so help me Masters of JQ and JQM D:

Answer (score 0):

> $(document).ready(function){...}; load dynamic list only once.When i
> go to other menu,data from list.html dissapear. When I click in some
> element from list.html,jquery code dont load data in details.html

You insert all your pages as divs, and do transition between them.
Here is an example code from the jquery official documentation about how to create "multiple divs" and toggle between them

> Body consisting of several div elements which are enhanced using the
> page widget. Each such page has an id attribute to distinguish it from
> other pages.

The pages can be interlinked using anchors.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go To Page 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#page1" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go Back To Page 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you are using jquery mobile 1.4.5, you can use [this boilerplate code](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages-multi-page/) to get started quickly

> JQ 1.6.4 & JQM 1.4.5 are okey?

[According to official site](https://jquerymobile.com/), these are the jquery versions supported jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1.

Comment: First of all,thanks for the answer Santosh.I'm developing on Jquery less than 6 months so I'm trying to unsderstand all and I make some mistakes.Then that code is one file with multiple pages? I wanted multiple files with 1 or more pages

Comment: and if I do transition between them i need other code that execute Jquery when pagechange for example.I tried "pagechange" too.I still working on it

Comment: @JaimeGarcia Yes you can have multiple pages, but then you will have to include jquery files and assets in every html.